# What is a kVA in simple terms, for somebody who doesn't know electrical engineering?

Tags: load, ac-dc, volts

I have a DC circuit that runs on 8.1 A × 12 V (97.2 W). Power is supplied from a AC-DC transformer that plugs into a socket.

How many of these can I run in a place that provides a maximum of three-phase 30 kVA?

I cannot make sense of the kVA definition and it is beyond my comprehension. I do not understand real power, apparent power, power factors, resistive load, reactive load, linear load, nor can I calculate these.

Is there a simple answer?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but if the concept of VA is beyond your comprehension, I would suspect you are also not qualified to install anything that deals with that kind of power.

Comment: Not taken wrong way. I'm not planning on installing myself. I just need to understand what's available to me before I hire an electrician. I dont want to hire an electrician only to find out that the place I've acquired doesn't provide sufficient energy for my operations.

Comment: Get the electrician first to make sure the calculations are correct then find the suitable place...

Comment: In my experience, an electrician would usually come over first and asses the situation, free of charge. Only after this they would provide you with a quote and you can agree on the terms and cost.

Comment: See my previous answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/300296/what-does-the-value-of-reactive-power-represent-physically

Comment: Let me guess: cryptocurrency miners?

Answer (score 1):

Transformers are rated in kVA which if the load was pure linear resistive heater loads then kVA=kW kilowatts while some converter is going to be also storing some energy called Reactive which adds to the DC load here which is tiny V*I= watts.

Normally Amp breaker ratings may exceed kVA/V=kiloAmps at line V but is chosen for protection of wires but the transformer will be fused for kVA per phase divided by kV voltage to get rated current.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the effects of efficiency and non-linear load, you can divide 30 kVA by 97.2 watts, 30,000 / 97.2 = 309, and say that you can connect 309 of the devices in question. You might make a rough estimate that the ignored effects might cut that number in half and limit the allowable number to 150 units. Beyond that, you need a qualified person to look at the specifications of the device and the details of your location.